# Doppler cooling limit and the Heisenberg uncertainty limit

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, cold-atoms

In laser cooling, the forces arise because of the discreet momentum exchange between the atoms and the laser field. This exchange of momentum also constitutes a heating mechanism. Relating the heating rate to the cooling rate and in the low intensity limit results in the Doppler cooling limit, see [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/9783527600441.oe005) for a derivation. The Doppler limited temperature is given by

$$T_\text{D}=\frac{\hbar\gamma}{2k_B}\tag{1},$$

where $\gamma$ is the natural linewidth of the cooling transition.

However, I've been able to derive the same result by just considering the Heisenberg uncertainty relation. Unfortunately, I don't quite understand what I've done and whether I've just forced the correct result.

The Heisenberg uncertainty relation can be stated as

$$\Delta E\Delta t\ge\frac{\hbar}{2}\tag{2}.$$

From the Boltzmann distribution, a gas at a temperature $T$, $k_BT$ is a measure of the spread in the energy. So we can relate the uncertainty in energy to the temperature $\Delta E=k_BT$. The uncertainty in time I've then related to the natural linewidth by $\Delta t=1/\gamma$. Subbing these into Eq.(2) gives Eq.(1). However, I can't seem to reason the $\Delta t=1/\gamma$ relation. Can anyone elaborate on this? Or explain whether I've forced the derivation?

Answer (score 1):

The real derivation of the *Doppler limit* comes from considerations of the mean momentum, which undergoes a random walk because of the absorption/scattering processes, as it's done [here](http://budker.berkeley.edu/PhysicsH190/Lasercool_notes.pdf) - this is different from the *recoil* limit which comes from the recoil energy of a *single* spontaneously emitted photon.

An intuitive way to obtain the Doppler limit is to set the thermal energy $k_B T$ to half the energy spread associated with the finite lifetime of the transition, so $\hbar \gamma/2$. That is because in laser cooling with two counterpropagating beams, the moving atom needs to be able distinguish which one is coming towards it "faster" and hence has a redder Doppler shift, for that will be the one to be absorbed and hence to provide the momentum "kick". But when the difference between the two beams' Doppler shift is on the order of $\hbar \gamma$, the atom itself does not have enough *resolution* to tell them apart. So the total difference between the two beams needs to be $> \hbar\gamma$, so each beam should be $> \hbar \gamma /2$.

Your derivation may be a coincidence or maybe a consequence that the derivation behind the energy-time uncertainty relation is actually quite similar to that of the momentum random walk I mentioned at the beginning. The $\Delta E \Delta t$ result is not *really* an uncertainty relation, because time is not an operator. Its interpretation (and derivation) is that in a time interval $\Delta t$, the observable (in this case energy) will deviate from its eigenvalue by up to $\Delta E$. Its derivation just uses time evolution and Schrodinger equation, hence why I am saying is probably the same as the momentum random walk.